# INotifyPropertyChanged for property of property

Tags: silverlight, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I think the best way to describe this question is with a very simple example....

Imagine that you have two classes.  Call them `Train` and `Status`.

In the `DomainService` for `Train` you have a line that looks like:

```
[Include]
public Status { get; set;}
```

The `Status` has two properties: `Name` and `DisplayColor`.

1. Now, bind an `ObservableCollection` of `Train` objects to a `DataGrid`
2. Bind an `ObservableCollection` of `Status` to another `DataGrid`.
3. Then update one of the `Status` objects.
4. **Is there any way to make this change reflect automatically in the `DataGrid` holding the `Train` objects?**

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want (assuming both the service and Status implement INotifyPropertyChanged):

```
private Status _status;

[Include]
public Status Status
{
  get { return _status; }
  set 
  {
    if (_status == value) return;

    if (_status != null)
       _status.PropertyChanged -= NotifyStatusChanged;

    _status = value;

    // Whatever your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged looks like.
    RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(()=> Status);

    if (_status != null)
       _status.PropertyChanged += NotifyStatusChanged;
  }
}

private void NotifyStatusChanged(object o, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Whatever your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged looks like.
    RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(()=> Status);
}
```